# Why does softmax provide always a probability of 1.0?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, mnist

I have been trying with simple mnist example. Sorry if the question is the very basic one.

```python
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import np_utils

def myModel():

    model= Sequential()
    layer1 = Dense(1024, input_shape=(784,), activation='relu')
    layer2 = Dense(512, activation='relu')
    layer3 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    model.add (layer1)
    model.add (layer2)
    model.add(layer3)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Inside the main function "
    model = myModel()
    (trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = mnist.load_data()
    print ("TrainX shape is ", trainX.shape)
    trainX = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1] * trainX.shape[2])
    trainY = np_utils.to_categorical(trainY, 10)
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=200, epochs=1)

    print ("Let's predict now..")
    print ("Shae of x and shape of 100" , trainX.shape, trainX[10].shape)
    result = model.predict(trainX[100].reshape(1,784 ))
    print result

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    plt.imshow(trainX[1100].reshape(28,28))
    plt.show()
```

The output value of the last layer is

```python
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

How do i have to interpret this result?. Is this not a probability distribution for the result?. if not how do i get the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*In theory*, there should be nothing strange with a probability distribution like `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`, i.e. `p[5]=1` and `p[k]=0` for all other `k`... All entries are in `[0, 1]` and they sum up to `1.0`.

*In practice*, you are making the mistake of not normalizing your input data `trainX` (the [Keras MNIST MLP example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) should be your guide here); adding

```python
trainX = trainX.astype('float32')
trainX /= 255
```

before fitting the model, we get (notice how smaller the *loss* will be during fitting, compared with your own trial):

```python
result = model.predict(trainX[100].reshape(1,784 ))
# result:
array([[6.99907425e-04, 7.85773620e-04, 1.73144764e-03, 9.31426825e-04,
        5.75593032e-04, 9.49266493e-01, 1.22108115e-02, 1.03891856e-04,
        3.18745896e-02, 1.82012399e-03]], dtype=float32)
```

Is it a good result?

```python
np.argmax(result)
# 5

np.argmax(trainY[100])  # true label
# 5
```

It seems it is indeed...

Comment: StackOverflow definitely need such authors like you. Gr8 Help. Thanks.

Comment: @Whoami you are very welcome; care to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions, one in your title, one the body. For the first one, yes, softmax always sums to one. Recall how [it is defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function):

exp(x) / ∑ exp(x)

which always sums to one due to the normalisation. At the beginning of training, the output should be random and approximately uniform and after good training, you expect an output like you have; At least for clear images. For other images, you may get `[0,0.3, 0.7, 0,…]` where two (or more) labels are seen as possible for an image.